# Input not being updated with simulate change when using Enzyme and React

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have a component with an input like this:

```
const myComponent = () => {
  return (
    <h2>My component</h2>
    <input type="text" value="initial"/>
  )
}

export default MyComponent;
```

I am trying to test value change in this component using Enzyme and Jest like below.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import MyComponent from '../src/MyComponent';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
  });
  it('changes the input', () => {
    wrapper.find('input').simulate('change', {target: {value: 'new value' }});
    expect(wrapper.find('input').prop('value')).toBe('new value');
  });
});
```

The problem is that the value is still ''. I have tried to do wapper.update() or wrapper.setProps({}) but the value does not change. What's wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I wasn't changing the value. My component should de like the following code:

```
import {React, useState} from 'react';

const myComponent = () => {
  const [value, setValue[ = useState('');
  return (
    <h2>My component</h2>
    <input type="text" value={value} />
  )
}

export default MyComponent;
```